git config meaning of new entry
I have found the recent snippet in a .git/config file
[diff "rails_credentials"]
    textconv = bin/rails credentials:diff

what does this imply?

man git config; /diff.*textconv (assuming less(1) pager)

Or https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-diffltdrivergttextconv -> https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_performing_text_diffs_of_binary_files
